# Add new element into DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am struggling with adding new "button" element into my "list". I was trying to append or someting els but doesn't work. It is not usual ul to li. If you ask why button parent it is form bootstrap list-group

UPDATE JS. IT is now adding "button but not corectlly.

```
     <div class="list-group">
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item">
                        <ul class="desc">
                            <li class="t-desc50">Add Device</li>

                            <li class="t-desc55"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                        </ul>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item" id="new-item>
                            <ul class="desc">
                                <li class="t-desc">Lamp</li>
                                <li class="t-desc2">5 kwH</li>
                                <li class="t-desc3"><label class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                                      </label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </button>
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item" id="new-item>
                                <ul class="desc">
                                    <li class="t-desc">AC</li>
                                    <li class="t-desc2">5 kwH</li>
                                    <li class="t-desc3"><label class="switch">
                                            <input type="checkbox">
                                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                                          </label></li>
                                </ul>
                            </button>
                 </div>
```

JS

```
 document.querySelector('.fa-plus').addEventListener('click', addItem

  );

  function addItem() {
var list = document.getElementById("list-group");

var li = document.createElement("button");
li.setAttribute('id', li);
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(li));
list.appendChild(li);
 }
```

Comment: `addEventListener` takes a function. It looks like you left out some code?

Comment: remove the `()` in addElement on `addeventlistener` .Its just perfrom like `IIF`

Comment: working but not adding same "buttons"

Comment: You will make confusion for other people calling a button tag `li` in your javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an element to the dom, you can use :

`var element = document.createElement(tagName);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Then append your element.

You can add event listener to `element`, and add class before if you need.

**Comment answer**

The code you need is probably something like that :

```
function addItem() { 
  var list = document.getElementById('list-group')

  //Button
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.classList.add("list-group-item");

  //Ul
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  ul.classList.add("desc");

  //li
  var liFirst = document.createElement('li');
  var liSecond = document.createElement('li');
  var liThird = document.createElement('li');
  liFirst.innerHTML = "Lamp"
  liSecond.innerHTML = "5 kwH"

  //Label
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  label.classList.add("switch");
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.classList.add("slider");
  span.classList.add("round");

  label.append(input)
  label.append(span)

  liThird.append(label)

  ul.append(liFirst)
  ul.append(liSecond)
  ul.append(liThird)
  button.append(ul)

  list.append(button)
}
```

Comment: nearly there but how to add also class of "desc" this class is esential

Comment: `element.classList.add("desc")`, element must be defined before (`var element = document.getElementMyId(...)` if element exist in DOM, or `var element = document.createElement(...)` if you create the element)

Comment: this is working for some how but adding empty "button" without ul and li in it

`function addItem() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('list-group');

    //modalContent is created and inserted in element which id is myModal 
    modalContent = document.createElement("button");
    modalContent.classList.add("list-group-item");
    modalContent.classList.add("desc");
   



    modal.append(modalContent)
}`

Comment: I missunderstand what you needed, i made an edit, hope it will work

Comment: this is what i am geting in console `<button class="list-group-item"><ul class="desc"><li></li></ul></button>`

Comment: i just need to be able to when i click fa-plus to add this `<button type="button" class="list-group-item"><ul class="desc"><li class="t-desc">Lamp</li><li class="t-desc2">5 kwH</li>
                                    <li class="t-desc3"><label class="switch">
                                            <input type="checkbox">
                                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                                          </label></li>
                                </ul>
                            </button>`

Comment: Edited :)

You need your `div` to have `id=list-group`

Comment: @Damien `... i just need to be able to when i click fa-plus to add this ...` may you just read the answers of others too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function as argument instead of calling it:

```
// wrong:
document.querySelector('.fa-plus').addEventListener('click', addElement());

// right:
document.querySelector('.fa-plus').addEventListener('click', addElement);
```

`addEventListener` expects a callback function, if you call the function first, you are sending the result of the function as argument, which is wrong.

You need to pass the `addElement` function instead, so the `addEventListener` calls it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several semantic errors in both the markup and the code. Firstly, `<button type="button" class="list-group-item" id="new-item>` misses the closing double quotes. Secondly, one should not use an `id` twice as the OP's example does with `id="new-item`. At third `addEventListener` misses its 3rd argument.

Besides that it will be hard if not impossible to capture any click event on the `fa-plus` classified `<i/>` element; one should use the whole button instead ... that's what a button is for.

Additionally one might rethink how to retrieve/query the structure one wants to add the new element to. I would suggest a more generic approach that retrieves the top most group parent from within the structure where the click event did occur, thus one can make use of more than just on `list-group` classified element.

Having sanitized the code the OP'S given example then might look similar to this ...

```js
function getClosestParentByClassName(elm, className) {
    while (elm && !elm.classList.contains(className)) {
        elm = elm.parentNode;
    }
    return elm;
}

function addItem(evt) {
  //console.log(evt.currentTarget);
    var
        groupParent   = getClosestParentByClassName(evt.currentTarget, 'list-group'),
        itemBlueprint = groupParent && groupParent.querySelector('.list-group-item.new-item'),
        newGroupItem  = (itemBlueprint && itemBlueprint.cloneNode(true)) || createDefaultItem();

  //console.log(groupParent, itemBlueprint, newGroupItem);

    if (newGroupItem) {
        // do whatever needs to be done in order to place the right content into this structure.

        groupParent.appendChild(newGroupItem);
    }
}


getClosestParentByClassName(document.querySelector('.fa-plus'), 'list-group-item').addEventListener('click', addItem, false);


function createDefaultItem() {
    var
        renderContainer = document.createElement('div');

    renderContainer.innerHTML = [
        '<button type="button" class="list-group-item new-item">'
    ,       '<ul class="desc">'
    ,           '<li class="t-desc">@missing t-desc</li>'
    ,           '<li class="t-desc2">@missing t-desc2</li>'
    ,           '<li class="t-desc3">'
    ,               '<label class="switch">'
    ,                   '<input type="checkbox">'
    ,                   '<span class="slider round"></span>'
    ,               '</label>'
    ,           '</li>'
    ,       '</ul>'
    ,   '</button>'

    ].join('');

    return renderContainer.querySelector('button');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item">
        <ul class="desc">
            <li class="t-desc50">Add Device</li>
            <li class="t-desc55"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item new-item">
        <ul class="desc">
            <li class="t-desc">Lamp</li>
            <li class="t-desc2">5 kwH</li>
            <li class="t-desc3">
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item new-item">
        <ul class="desc">
            <li class="t-desc">AC</li>
            <li class="t-desc2">5 kwH</li>
            <li class="t-desc3">
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

got it!

```
function addItem() {
var list = document.getElementById('list-group')
var button = document.createElement('button');
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var liFirst = document.createElement('li');
var liSecond = document.createElement('li');
var liThird = document.createElement('li');

button.classList.add("list-group-item");
ul.classList.add("desc");
liFirst.classList.add("t-desc")
liSecond.classList.add("t-desc2")
liThird.classList.add("t-desc3")
liFirst.innerText = 'TV'
liSecond.innerText = '5kwh'
liThird.innerHTML = `<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>`

ul.append(liFirst)
ul.append(liSecond)
ul.append(liThird)
button.append(ul)

list.append(button)
```

}

Comment: last question how to append to add button not at the end of list but at the beggining?

Comment: Use `prepend` instead of `append`